# Understanding of .loc in Pandas to save variables in specific cell of a dataframe

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I don't understand the behaviour `.loc` or `.at`, when I want to save a variable in a specific cell of a dataframe. Can somebody help me to understand, please?

My failing working example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
print(pd.__version__)
from platform import python_version
print(python_version())



df=pd.DataFrame(index=[0,1,2,3],columns=['A','B'])

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[np.array([1,2,3]), np.array([4,5,6]), np.array([7,8,9]), np.array([10,11,12]), np.array([13,14,15])],'b':[5,5,12,123,6]})

display(df)
df.loc[0,'c']='string 0'
df.loc[1,'c']='string 1'
df.loc[2,'c']='string 2'
df.loc[3,'c']='string 3'


print(df.index.values)

testdata=np.array(np.arange(0,3648,1),dtype=np.float32)
print('----------testdata----------')
print(type(testdata))
print(testdata.dtype)
print(testdata.shape)

print('----------file_handle----------')
file_handle=np.array([1],dtype=np.int64)
print(file_handle)
print(type(file_handle))
print(file_handle.dtype)


if not 'new_column' in df.columns:
        df=df.assign(new_column=None)


display(df)
df.loc[file_handle,'new_column']=[testdata]

display(df)
```

Result: `ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an ndarray`

But with `df.at[file_handle[0],'new_column']=[testdata]`, `df.at[1,'new_column']=[testdata]` it works. I don't understand. With `df.loc[file_handle[0],'new_column']=testdata` it does not work either.
In other places of my code, I can use as row index `[1]` to assign dicts or scalars into one specific location, but no numpy arrays.

Thank you for your explanation and insight. I would be thankful to understand, how to use `.loc` and `at` and what variables they accept, both as row index, but also as item stored in the dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have an ndarray on the right side, Pandas will not treat it like any Python object that can be inserted into the DataFrame. Instead you run into a code path that tries to set multiple values at multiple locations from that array, hence the error message pointing out `when setting with an ndarray`.

Consider some working multiloc code like

```
df.loc[[0,1,3], ['b', 'new_column']] = np.array([[4,5], [6,7], [8,9]])
```

Here, the shape of the ilocs on the left side is the same shape as the array on the right side, and it sets all the values successfully.

In your code, the list of the testdata array of shape (3648) is treated like a 2D-array of shape (1, 3648) by Pandas in this operation. This shape does not match the ilocs on the left side, thus Pandas throws an error about not being able to match them up.

The correct way to handle this issue is to use `.at` instead, which can only handle a single location, and won't run into the ndarray setting codepath.

Comment: Hi @w-m. Thank you for your explanation. And I guess, it does not matter if the row index is an int, np.ndarray, or a list? 
For `.loc` Pandas will choose a different code path to verify the row indices?

Comment: Yes, you can assume Pandas treats all list-like variants the same way in the multiloc code paths in `.loc`/`.iloc`.